# In Access VBA, how do I get DISTINCT values from multiple columns of a table to be the row source of a combo box?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a ComboBox `combo1` and 3 fields `area1`, `area2` and `area3`. The fields can be null or duplicates. I want `combo1` to only display those values which are NOT duplicates and Not nulls. My current code displays all the values from the fields including all duplicates and Nulls. Its as though the `DISTINCT` is ignored completely. I am definitely getting it all wrong. I would be grateful if someone helps me with this.
`tblMain`:

```
+-----------+----------+-------------+
+ area1     + area2    +    area3    +
+---------- +----------+-------------+
+ Islington + Barnet   +             +
+-----------+----------+-------------+
+ Stratford +          + Islington   +
+-----------+----------+-------------+
+   603     +    501   + Islington   +
+-----------+----------+-------------+
```

Expected Results in `combo1`:

```
501
603
Barnet
Islington
Stratford
```

Below is the state of my current code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim rowS As String

rowS = "SELECT DISTINCT area1, area2, area3 FROM tblMain"

With Me.combo1
Me.combo1.RowSource = rowS
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want a distinct list of area codes or a list of distinct area combinations?

Comment: @FunThomas I am looking for a distinct list of area names from the fields. My main aim is not see repeated area names or null values in the row source of the combo box.

Comment: Well is there a chance that area2 & area3 is causing said duplication? Distinct means distinct groupings of those columns.

Comment: I have tried to use UNION on the Columns which seems to be leading me in the right direction but I am not sure if this is luck or the right approach. `rowS = "SELECT DISTINCT area1 FROM tbMain UNION SELECT DISTINCT area2 FROM tblMain UNION SELECT DISTINCT area3 FROM tblMain"`

Comment: @Fil At this point its going to be real difficult to help you unless we see the data from tblMain for area1, area2 and area3. Please provide so we can actually be of assistance

Comment: Also, why are you putting brackets around you string vairable in the row source assignment? that seems off to me

Comment: @DougCoats Coats Code edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, try this and make sure it works for you.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim rowS As String

    rowS =  "SELECT area1 as Area FROM tblMain WHERE area1 IS NOT NULL UNION "
    rowS = rowS & "SELECT area2 as Area FROM tblMain  WHERE area2 IS NOT NULL UNION "
    rowS = rowS & "SELECT area3 as Area FROM tblMain WHERE area3 IS NOT NULL "

    Me.combo1.RowSource = rowS
End Sub
```

EDIT - I have replciated your issue and I can verify that you must have empty strings in your columns. Please verify for us will you?

[image]

Comment: UNION does not allow duplicate rows so DISTINCT is not needed.

Comment: fair enough - I probably dont need the sub query either

Comment: I just REALLY want the jet engine to do unnecessary work LOL

Comment: And yes, I would say not to nest query. And use an alias name like Data or something other than Field.

Comment: Field is a reserved word? I guess it isnt in sql server,  but i forget that access has its own list of words

Comment: @DougCoats The code seems to work but doesn't ignore nulls.

Comment: Are there actual nulls or do you have empty strings in those fields?

Comment: Following @June7 advice, `rowS = "SELECT DISTINCT area1 FROM tbMain UNION SELECT DISTINCT area2 FROM tblMain UNION SELECT DISTINCT area3 FROM tblMain"` Seems to be doing the same thing but the problem is, how do I handle null Values?

Comment: Don't think that is quite what I advised. See @DougCoats revised answer.

Comment: @Fil please let us know about empty string in your columns

Comment: @DougCoats sorry i was away. Yes the columns do contain empty strings.